# Add a for each within a table row of another for each in JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, foreach, datatable

Here is the output of my current for each:
[image: 1]

```
var tbody="";
$.each(response.all_groups, function (key, group) {
tbody+='<tr>'+
            '<td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">'+group.group_id+'</p>'+group.group_description+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+group.group_type_name+'</td>'+
            '<td></td>'+
            '<td>'+getgroupstatus(group.effective_start_datetime, group.effective_end_datetime)+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.id+'" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> '+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.group_id+'" title="delete '+ group.group_name +'" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
});
```

My issue is that when I try to add another `for each` inside the empty `<td>` tag, the other two succeeding it goes missing, what went wrong?

**CODE WITH THE SECOND FOR EACH:**

```
var tbody="";
const arr = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
$.each(response.all_groups, function (key, group) {
tbody+='<tr>'+
            '<td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">'+group.group_id+'</p>'+group.group_description+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+group.group_type_name+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
            $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                });
            +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+getgroupstatus(group.effective_start_datetime, group.effective_end_datetime)+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.id+'" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> '+
                '<button type="button" value="'+group.group_id+'" title="delete '+ group.group_name +'" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
});
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Remove the `+` in `'<td>'+ $.each` and add `tbody +=` in `});+'</td>` it it's like `}); tbody += '</td>`

Comment: my for each is not showing up anymore after trying this

Comment: nevermind, tweaked the code a bit, for each is now showing up, thanks